# How to create a bidirectional channel between processes?

Tags: php, c++, posix

In my project, I needed to run a php script from c ++, pass standard input to it, and select standard output. To do this, I create a child process using fork (), open pipes using pipe (), reassign I / O flows through dup2, and run the script using execlp (). I wrote a small program for tests, but it does not work, freezes, waits until the child process writes something to the channel, but this does not happen, what am I doing wrong?

cpp code

```
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    int pipe_in[2];
    int pipe_out[2];
    pipe(pipe_in);
    pipe(pipe_out);
    if ((pid = fork()) > 0)
    {
        close(pipe_in[0]);
        close(pipe_out[1]); и

        std::string msg = "hello world\n";
        char buf[256];
        write(pipe_in[1], msg.c_str(), msg.length());
        read(pipe_out[0], buf, 255);
        std::string temp = buf;
        std::cout « temp;
    }
    else
    {
        close(pipe_in[1]);
        close(pipe_out[0]);
        dup2(pipe_in[0], 0);
        dup2(pipe_out[1], 1);
        if(execlp("php", "/home/anton/test1.php", NULL) < 0)
        std::cout «"((("; 

    }
}
```

php code

```
<?php
$line = trim(fgets(STDIN));
echo $line;
echo "11111";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your pipe and I/O redirection is sound. I think the issue you are dealing with is the misuse of the `execlp` call. The first argument should be the path to the file you want to execute. The rest of the arguments will effectively be the `argv` for the program you want to exec. So if you think about it, the second argument to `execlp` is going to be `argv[0]` (the program name) in that exec'd program. So you could do something like:

```
execlp(
    "/usr/bin/php", // actual path to executable file
    "myphp", // argv[0]
    "/home/anton/test1.php", // argv[1]
    NULL // sentinel
);
```

I purposely wrote an exaggerated program name for the second argument so you get the idea. Also, I don't work with php so I'm assuming the php executable is at `/usr/bin/php`. You might be able to verify that by running: `command -v php`. Hope this helps.